# How to generate unique product Serial no based on productID and productCategoryId using LINQ?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm trying to generate unique product serial or tags no based on productId and product categoryId ?

```
    public string GetProductSerialNo(int productID,int categoryId)
    {

        var productSerialNo= (from a in db.AssetProductInfo
                  where a.ProductId == productID && a.CategoryId==categoryId
                  select a.ID).Max() + 1;

        return productSerialNo.ToString();
    }
```

The above code works if there exists at least one products into table. Is there any better solution to generate product serial no using LINQ Query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If two people run this code simultaneously, they'll get the same ID

Comment: Typically the best way to do this is to make the ID auto-incrementing. Look it up, and you'll find examples all over the place.

Answer (score 0):

**you can add your first two character of category name and also with unique no from this function and also you can add date time with millisecond.**

```
public string GetProductSerialNo(int productID,int categoryId,string CategoryFist2Character)
{

    var productSerialNo= (from a in db.AssetProductInfo
              where a.ProductId == productID && a.CategoryId==categoryId
              select a.ID).Max() + UniqueNumber(CategoryFist2Character);

    return productSerialNo.ToString();
}
public string UniqueNumber(string CategoryFist2Character)
{
    Random unique1 = new Random();
    string s = CategoryFist2Character;
    int unique;
    int n = 0;
    while (n < 10)
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            s += unique1.Next(10).ToString();

        }
        else
        {
            unique = unique1.Next(52);
            if (unique < this.characters.Length)
                s = String.Concat(s, this.characters[unique]);
        }
        Label2.Text = s.ToString();
        n++;
    }
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the concurrency issue of two people running it at the same time. It just makes it far more unlikely. The best way to _guarantee_ a unique identifier in the database is to let the database do it.